# Find Typescript version in the Atom editor and update TypeScript if necessary

Tags: javascript, typescript, atom-editor

How do I find the version number of TypeScript installed on my Windows computer?  I'm using the Atom editor and have the atom-typscript package installed.  If its not an up to date version, how to I update to the current version of TypeScript?

Comment: In the atom-typescript [faq](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/faq.md) it says it uses [ntypescript](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ntypescript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the atom-typescript package you just need to update the package itself (on Atom's Settings->Updates screen) to get a newer TypeScript build. More info can be found in the [FAQ](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/faq.md#which-version-of-typescript-does-atom-typescript-use).

The version is driven by [`package.json`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/6e33ea6fc553b7ae3764950f9fe383a998e3b647/package.json#L55)

Comment: Thanks.  My atom-typescript updated to 5.2.0  I presume this means it contains TypeScript 1.5.0, the recent release.  I looked at atom-typescript's package.json and it is far too complex to make any sense of it, even using Find.  It would be nice to have the TypeScript version explicitly stated somewhere, e.g., on the message that TypeScript has emitted on file save.  Alternatively, the FAQ should say how to get an explicit readout of the TypeScript version.

Comment: As best that I can tell, atom-typescript does not show which version of typescript it uses. Here are some useful npm commands.  npm outdated --depth=0 helps to identify outdated modules.   npm show typescript version   will tell you the specific version installed on your computer.   npm update -g typescript  will update your installed typescript module